# Xamarin Forms: Very slow performance when making calls to ASP.NET (ASMX) web service

Tags: performance, xamarin.forms, asmx

After upgrading our Xamarin Forms project from VS 2017 (Xamarin Forms 4.2.0.848062) to VS 2019 (Xamarin Forms 4.6.0.800) during stress and performance testing we noticed significant performance degradation when downloading files from ASP.NET (ASMX) web service. This is happening for Android and iOS but the problem is especially severe for Android.
For Android project we tried to set:
HTTPClient Implementation build option to Android,
SSL/TLS Implementation build option to Native TLS 1.2+
but it didn't improve performance by much.

Testing procedure:
Our Xamarin Forms app sequentially downloads 150 files ( each files size is roughly 1 MB) from ASP.NET (ASMX) web service.
The results of our testing:
Android:
App built with VS 2019 (Xamarin Forms 4.6.0.800) is 35-45% slower then app built with VS 2017 (Xamarin Forms 4.2.0.848062).
iOS:
App built with VS 2019 (Xamarin Forms 4.6.0.800) is 10-20% slower then app built with VS 2017 (Xamarin Forms 4.2.0.848062).

We tried different IIS Authentication methods (Basic, Digest, Windows) and web service binding protocols (HTTP and HTTPS) but that didn't improve performance.

This is very serious issue for us and it is important to improve performance at least to the level of VS 2017 (Xamarin Forms 4.2.0.848062) build.

Any help or suggestions or workarounds will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for help,

Leo

Comment: have you tried profiling the old and new versions of the app to determine where the bottleneck(s) may be?  I doubt the version of VS or XF is the culprit - it is more likely a change in the Xamarin iOS/Android version.  And are you testing apples-to-apples, using the same hardware and OS version for both?  Finally, do you have control over the services?  ASMX are fairly outdated compared to REST, and it may be worth considering an upgrade.

Comment: We didn’t profile our app in this case bit we have some performance metrics in our code to help app optimization. All web calls made inside platform-specific projects (Android/iOS) using generated web service proxy classes.We know that the bottleneck is when multiple web service proxy calls to retrieve files from server are made. Migrating to REST is an option and long term goal but it would take some time and for now we would like somehow improve performance without changing our web service implementation. Thanks, Leo

Comment: I'd suggest creating a simple project that demonstrates the problem and submit it to the Xamarin team.  It will also allow you to do some profiling - which I mean in the general sense, not using the Profiler tool.  Compare transfer times for each file, the time used to establish connections, etc.

Comment: @Jason I've already submitted this issue with Xamarin Forms team and waiting to hear from them if they need additional information. Thanks. Leo